# Spring Data Neo4j - Getting an exception when running a cypher query

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm getting a strange exception when trying to run a simple cypher query. First i'll introduce my code, and then i'll show what cause the exception. So i have the following classes:

A simple class to represent a user profile:

```
public abstract class Profile extends AbstractEntity {

    @Indexed
    ProfileType profileType;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "name")
    String firstName;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "name")
    String lastName;

    @Indexed
    EyeColor eyeColor;

    @Indexed    
    HairColor hairColor;

    @Indexed
    Nationality nationality;

    @Indexed
    int height;

    public Profile() {
        setProfileType();
    }

    public Profile(String firstName, String lastName, Nationality nationality, EyeColor eyeColor, HairColor hairColor, int height) {
        this();
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setNationality(nationality);
        this.setHairColor(hairColor);
        this.setEyeColor(eyeColor);
        this.setHeight(height);
    }   

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

And a simple class, which inherit from `Profile`, and represents a civilian:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Civilian extends Profile {

    @GraphProperty(propertyType = Long.class)
    DateTime dateOfBirth;

    @Indexed
    boolean missing;

    @RelatedTo
    @Fetch
    Set<Casualty> casualties = new HashSet<Casualty>(); //TODO: design

    public Civilian() {
        this.profileType = ProfileType.CIVILIAN;
    }

    public Civilian(String firstName, String lastName, Nationality nationality, EyeColor eyeColor, HairColor hairColor, int height, DateTime dateOfBirth, boolean missing) {
        super(firstName, lastName, nationality, eyeColor, hairColor, height);
        this.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
        this.setMissing(missing);
    }

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

So i created the following repository for the `Civilian` class:

```
public interface CivilianRepository extends GraphRepository<Civilian> {
    @Query("start n=node(*) where n.firstName=~{0} return n")   
    Page<Civilian> findCiviliansProperties(String firstName, Pageable page);    
}
```

Ok. So i created few `Civilian` nodes, and populated the graph with them. There are no other nodes in the graph, except for the `Civilian` nodes. When i run the `findCiviliansProperties` method, i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement start n=node(*) where n.firstName=~{0} return n skip 0 limit 10; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement start n=node(*) where n.firstName=~{0} return n skip 0 limit 10; nested exception is org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException: The property 'firstName' does not exist on Node[0]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.query(CypherQueryEngine.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findCiviliansProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.findCiviliansProperties(Unknown Source)
    at org.technion.socialrescue.playground.Playground.main(Playground.java:38)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement start n=node(*) where n.firstName=~{0} return n skip 0 limit 10; nested exception is org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException: The property 'firstName' does not exist on Node[0]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.parseAndExecuteQuery(CypherQueryEngine.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.query(CypherQueryEngine.java:49)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException: The property 'firstName' does not exist on Node[0]
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Property.apply(Property.scala:35)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Property.apply(Property.scala:29)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.RegularExpression.isMatch(Predicate.scala:259)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:29)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.hasNext(Iterator.scala:390)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:333)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.SlicePipe.createResults(SlicePipe.scala:32)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ColumnFilterPipe.createResults(ColumnFilterPipe.scala:37)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:127)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:125)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:33)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:59)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:63)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.parseAndExecuteQuery(CypherQueryEngine.java:61)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: 'firstName' property not found for NodeImpl#0.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:184)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Property.apply(Property.scala:33)
    ... 38 more
```

So the most important thing about this exception is the following line - `The property 'firstName' does not exist on Node[0]`.. But how can it be? there are only `Civilian` nodes  in the graph, and they all have the `firstName` property. Can it be that the neo4j framework adds some more hidden nodes to my graph which i'm not aware of? Because when i change my query into this:

```
start n=node(*) where has(n.firstName) AND n.firstName=~{0} return n
```

Everything works fine...

What is wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neo4j` automatically comes with 1 node when you create a new instance, and that's the reference node. You should delete this.

```
graphDatabaseService.getNodeById(0).delete()
```

Comment: But why they create this node?

Comment: @royv See this answer (http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2011-February/006935.html) from one of the core developers.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense. But i would expect the user to add this node if he wants, and not the system to add it as its default behavior. Is there a way to create the graph without this node from the start? Its a bit ugly to add this line.

Comment: They are getting rid of this concept in the near future.